# Can node.js scan all network connection

Tags: node.js

I want to implement forced redirect page using node.js.

In detail, here is network settings:
Client -- Wifi AP (node.js running) -- Internet -- Web Page

Then, can AP side be implemented showing welcome page forcedly before connect to request page?

For example, client connect to AP via Wifi, and client want to connect some page like https://stackoverflow.com/.
But first time, client must see http://www.someofWelcomepage.com/ , and next time client want to connect any page he wants.
(Looks like wireless service in some hotel)

Is it possible to implement using node.js?